# Where can we find a config data in Windows

Tags: windows

In Windows, what are the built-in options to store config data (any data) locally?
I see three categories at least:

1. Files (such as .txt, .ini, .xml etc)
2. ODBC
3. Registry

Anything else?
I want to know if there are any other options.

Let's say you installed a software and you want to know where it is referencing for its own config data, where can we look for?

FYI:
OS: Windows 7 64 bit English version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty much your options, but I have to pull you up on number 2.  ODBC is not a location in which you can store data; it's a technology by which you can access data.  An application interacts with an ODBC driver and then that driver interacts with a data source.  That data source will most often be a database of some sort but certainly not always.  I think what you actually meant to say was "database", which may or may not be accessed via ODBC from an application.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Also thank you for the explanation regarding ODBC. I now understand it is a technology to access to database such as MS SQL / Access DB etc (but perhaps not MySQL unless MySQL ODBC connector is installed) . That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure that, this is what you need.

1. Click `Start`, point to `All Programs`, and then click `Accessories`.
2. Right-click `Command Prompt`, and then click Run As Administrator or `Start-> Run-> cmd`.
3. Type `bcdedit` at the command prompt

please refer this link for more info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404185.aspx